# how can I schedule Healthcheck in Kubernetes livenessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, schedule, kubernetes-health-check

since we need to stop a service in the kubernetes pot at night because we need to index something in our app(we also can't stop the pod because we need to index somethin in the pod.). While Index HealthEndpoint is unreachable, Prometheus warns that the service is not live. I want to disable liveness at night

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthcheck
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
  periodSeconds: 3
```

I've searched a lot on the internet but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use readinessProbe. The difference is that a service can recover from un-readiness while it cannot from failed liveness.
So as long as readinessProbe reports a failure, your pod will be taken out of service, i.e. it will not receive any requests, until readinessProbe reports health again.

Note that there is no connection between livenessProbe and readinessProbe. Both are checked independent from each other. So you may and should implement different check endpoints for them. While the readiness endpoint temporarily reports unhealthiness, your liveness endpoint still has to report health. Of course, you can ommit a livenessProbe if your are comfortable with that.